# iphone like location marker for android

Tags: android, iphone, ios, gps, google-maps-markers

As I know, iOS has a unique default marker presenting the user location (Marker that flashes some blue color)

Here's a picture: [image]

Is there something like it I can do in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to extent the class [MyLocationOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay) and override the [drawMyLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay#drawMyLocation%28android.graphics.Canvas,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView,%20android.location.Location,%20com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20long%29) method.

Excerpt from Android Docs:

**drawMyLocation** -
Draw the "my location" dot. By default, draws an animated "blue dot" asset, possibly surrounded by an outlining blue disk to represent accuracy. Also, if the user's position moves near the edge of the screen, and we've been given a [MapController](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController) in our constructor, we'll scroll to recenter the new reading.

Comment: I see, I was looking for that outlining blue disk thingy, what is it doing actually, accuracy of what?

Comment: I accepted your answer, though I'll still be glad for an answer for the accuracy thingy, thanks.

Comment: Shows the accuracy of the current method of reading your location. If it's from cell towers, it's not very accurate, so you'll have a big blue circle around which encompasses the area within which you are in. If you're using GPS, it'll be a lot more accurate, so it'll have a small circle around your location (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the MyLocationOverlay class. Here's a tutorial: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148

Comment: thanks but it's not what I've asked for, and as I read my question now, I see that it's blurry to understand what I want.

Comment: I wanted a marker that looks just like in the iphone, (it has an animation)

Comment: @idish, then it seems your real question should be "How do I do animation on Android?" Once you learn animation, then you can apply it to anything.